# Randomize CSS3 Animation Delay

Tags: javascript, css

I use CSS3 to create a slideshow using an `ol.slideshow`. Works.

I want to randomize the order of the images. As I use `li:nth-child(x) {animation-delay: x;}`
to show and hide my images, its useless to randomize the order of my `ol` elements.

To create a workaround, I thought about adding the classes `nth-child-1` to `nth-child-6` in a random order to my `li` elements on load, but I am not able to create such a snippet.

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/w02tg98m/4/) (Why does the animation not work inside a jsfiddle?)

How I would randomize my `li` elements:

```
$.fn.randomize = function(selector){
   var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
   $parents = $elems.parent();
   $parents.each(function(){
      $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
         return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
      }).detach().appendTo(this);
   });
   return this;
};
$('ol.slideshow').randomize();
```

Comment: are the images for list elements fetched from an API?

Comment: no, I just use `unsplash.it` to create a more "handsome" demo. The images are on my local server `images/slider/image1.jpg` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I could come up with. Single sweep. No hardcoding of the number of elements in the slideshow and a random class on each starting from nth-child-1

```
var elems = $("ol.slideshow li"); //gives you an array of li

var len = elems.length, randomNum = 0, randomEl, counter = 1;

//we keep removing the elements randomly giving them a class
//till we are not left with any element 
//this way you won't have to hard code "6" - the number of slideshow elements
while(len--) {
   randomNum = parseInt(Math.random()*len, 10);
   randomEl = elems.splice(randomNum, 1);
   $(randomEl).addClass('nth-child-' + counter);
   counter++;
}
```